# Python 3.x, how to read file contents ( into a one dimensional list)

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I'm new to python and self learning wherever possible. I'm trying to read data from a `.csv` file containing integers into a one dimensional array (python list).

The `.csv` file looks like this:

```
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"
"9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"
.
.
.
```

I tried like this:

```
l = []
f = open('file.csv', 'r')
for line in f:
      l.append(line)
f.close()
```

I get a 'list of lists' (2D array) instead of the linear list I intended.
Also, I would like the list to contain integers and not strings.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: The answer is already out there. How about reading up on lists and file imports?!

Comment: your code should give you 1D array - list with strings/lines.

Comment: Please Do Explain You Problem Properly.

Comment: if you need integers then you would have to split every line into list of substring and use `int()` woth every element in this list. If you will append single number to list then you get 1D array. You can also `l.extend(list)` or `l += list` to get 1D array.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are *not* getting a list of lists, but a list of strings (the lines in your file), with each string *looking* like a list. First, you need to split the lines. You *could* do this using `line.split(",")`, but since you are having a CSV file, you should instead just use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. This will also take care of removing the `"..."` for you.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    lst = []
    for line in r:
          lst.append(line)
```

Now, we have an actual list of lists: `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']]`

Next, if you want a *flat* list with all the numbers from all the lines, you should use `extend` instead of `append`, and you can also cast those `str` to `int`:

```
    for line in r:
        lst.extend(map(int, line))
```

This gives you `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`. You can also do all this in a single line using a list comprehension:

```
    lst = [int(s) for line in r for s in line]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply tobias_k, I tried your solution and it worked perfectly. Btw, the '...' are not present in the csv file, it was just my way of showing that more lines like the previous follow. I have a lot to learn :)

Comment: @johnnym With "removing the "..." " I meant removing the quotes around the individual entries. Also, if this helped you with your problem, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as being resolved. An happy holidays!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
with open("main.csv") as csvfile:
    tlines = [line.split(",", 2) for line in csvfile.readlines()]
    text = [" ".join(line) for line in tlines]
print text
```

It might help you.

Comment: This will not solve the problem with integers and strings and does not provide an explanation.

Comment: Why limit `split` to `2`? That does not make any sense.

Comment: I just cropped this code from my old project, that's it splits by 2.

Comment: Please try providing an answer to the question and not to a different problem.